# TypeScript Error : Argument of type 'never[] is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<getPostCommentsType | undefined>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use useState hook with typescript -

`const [comments, setComments] = useState<getPostCommentsType>()`

```
interface getPostCommentsType {
  comments: [
    id: string,
    reader: {
      id: string
      name: string
      email: string
      photo: {
        url: string
      }
    },
    comment: string
  ]
}
```

here I am setting it -       `setComments(await getComments(postId))`

```
const getComments = async (postId: string) => {
    const result: getPostCommentsType = await request(
      graphqlAPI,
      getPostCommentsQuery,
      {
        postId,
      }
    )
    return result.comments
```

and while setting the useState hook it is throwing the following error -

Argument of type 'never[] | [id: string, reader: { id: string; name: string; email: string; photo: { url: string; }; }, comment: string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<getPostCommentsType | undefined>'.
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<getPostCommentsType | undefined>'.ts(2345)

Comment: Is that error happening when you are calling setComments() ? can we see that code

Comment: @Will40  its happening when calling `setComments(await getComments(postId))` where getComments function is already defined with `getPostCommentsType`  return type.

Comment: im assuming await probably returns type never[] or something like that, I would call the api first so const comments = await getComments(); and then set state setComments(comments);

Comment: I had tried that but didn't worked out. @Will40

Comment: When you hover over comments on that statement, what is the type? The 'const comments = await getComments();' statement

Comment: Oh I have found the solution!!!. So basically the interface was having 'comments' key and its value as an array. But the getComments function was returning the result.comments itself so just the array part was passing down to the setState so I have to define a new interface just the type of array that I am getting.

Comment: Nice! Yeah you can also make an interface for comments and then use that to build the other interface to save code!